# Spring: JSP not reading passed ModelMap?

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get my JSP file to use the ModelMap passed by my servlet, but am getting an empty string. Been trying to debug this for a while now, but haven't made any progress. Anyone know of the problem? I'm using the latest Spring `WebInitializer` class. **index.jsp** prints `Hello` instead of `Hello Bob` for me.

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Hello ${test}
</body>
</html>
```

My controller **HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String foo(ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception {
        modelMap.addAttribute("test", "Bob");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.scan("com.myProject.bootstrap");

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));

        //Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        Set<String> mappingConflicts = dispatcher.addMapping("/views/*");
    }
}
```

Inside com.myProject.boostrap, I have **AppConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myProject"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

**My webapp folder tree**

[image]

Comment: According to me, you are trying to create a very basic spring application. Try this website: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/ . You don't need to code this extensively to achieve this. Spring is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning "forward:index" instead.

You can also change return type of your  handler to  'ModelAndView' and set view name and model while returning the modelAndView object.

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually I was using the wrong attribute name in my JSP page... so I got it working with ModelMap now. It worked with ModelAndView as well.